# passenger fails to start when restarting web server

Tags: passenger

I am seeing a weird passenger error when restarting httpd in /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```english
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.1896 30817/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.2390 30820/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1339 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.2393 30820/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.2991 30820/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1014 ]: Passenger core online, PID 30820
[Mon Jan 14 13:34:38.306645 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30775] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 14 13:34:38.306705 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30775] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.7734 30780/T1 age/Cor/TelemetryCollector.h:531 ]: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time
[ N 2019-01-14 13:34:38.8869 30780/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1324 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

The second to last line appears to be what's giving me an issue.

My best guess is that this was caused by reverting my VM to a snapshot, but I can't find any way to get passenger to run.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. I created an EC2 instance from a snapshot based AMI image. I'm struggling to figure this out before I complete rebuild my server image.

Comment: @kevin-l I am stuck with the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @acoustic_north did you find a solution for this. If so, please share it here.

Comment: Also having this issue, I am travelling to Australia from Canada, the application loads for my coworkers in Canada but here in Australia it refuses to load and prints this error.  Something related to timestamp sent from the client?  Super weird!!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this is the only place I've seen the same mistake I got, In my case the problem was that I turned on a force_ssl config in my rails app when I was accepting requests on port 80. So, if you have a rails app and have this message the solution might be to comment next line on production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Comment: Hi, production.rb under the redmine folder does not have this configuration. However, I still get this error.